# Python 2: function abstract type

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, type-hinting

I have a function that accepts a mapping that can be either a dictionary of a function, so I need to distinguish them. Usually I use some Abstract Base Class from `collections` and `isinstance`/`issubclass` to check argument types, but there is no ABC for functions. I know I can do `hasattr(mapping, "__call__")`, but I'm wondering whether there is something more specific for functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`callable(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable) which is available in Python 2.7 and Python 3.2+ but not in Python 3.0 or Python 3.1.

You can also use [`types.FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.FunctionType):

```
isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType)
```

Comment: `types.FunctionType` is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **[`types`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/types.html)** module for this which has, among others, **[`FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/types.html#types.FunctionType)** defined:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.FunctionType
<type 'function'>
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> isinstance(foo, types.FunctionType)
True
```